# How to add Multer for file upload

Tags: node.js, file-upload, multer

Here is router code:

```
router.route('/')
.post(validate(schema.storeLeaves), (req, res) => {
    leavesCtrl.store(req, res);
});
```

Here is function for adding record into database. Above code is calling below function.

```
var storage =   multer.diskStorage({

destination: function (req, file, callback) {
      callback(null, './uploads');
    },
    filename: function (req, file, callback) {
      callback(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now());
    }
  });

var upload = multer({ storage : storage}).single('document');

export function store(req, res) {
    upload(req,res,function(err) {
        if(err) {
            return res.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).json({
                error: err
            })
        }

        res.end("File is uploaded");

        const {leave_type, comments, date_from, date_to, blocked_dates} = req.body;

        leaves.forge({
            leave_type, comments, date_from, date_to, blocked_dates
        }).save()
            .then(leaves => res.json({
                    success: true,
                    data: leaves.toJSON()
                })
            )
            .catch(err => res.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).json({
                    error: err
                })
            );
    });

}
```

There is no error but also not uploading the file. Record is saving to database successfully.

Comment: Did you try to implement it using multer? You should at least give it a try. The multer documentation is straightforward.

Comment: Yes, I tried but it did not work. Later I restored original codes.

Comment: Post the code that you have used.

Comment: @Dijkstra I updated the codes. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to add Multer to your applications is using it as a middleware.

Try this :

```
const fs = require('fs-extra')
const multer = require('multer')
const storage = multer.diskStorage({

  destination: function (req, file, callback) {
    fs.mkdirSync('./uploads')
    callback(null, './uploads');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now());
  }
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage })

/* POST TEST Multer */
router.post('/', upload.single('file'), function (req, res, next) {
  res.send(req.file.path);
});
```

Also as a matter of clean code do not send `req` and `res` to your inside functions. Look at this [node.js best practices](https://github.com/goldbergyoni/nodebestpractices)

Comment: I tried it but no luck. I also added error handling from this [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#error-handling) but there is no error.

Comment: Did you create './upload' directory?
To work with destination function you have to work with exists path .
I changed my answer and it fully works with `fs`